# Pop up view different orientation problem in Android

Tags: android-layout, android

I have got horizontal oriented view and i want to show vertical oriented pop up view on it. Even i set vertical orientation on my pop up layer view it looks horizontal.

My pop Up view xml is :

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:weightSum="1" android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.35" android:layout_width="321dp">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And on my manifest file xml:

```
    <activity android:name="PopUpLayer" android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can have landscape view and portrait popup at the same time if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your xml as follows.Now check.

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:weightSum="1" android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.35" android:layout_width="321dp" android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If not work then see this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">

 <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
        <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>   
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Okay.Now see the output of the following xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
     </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: still it looks horizontal, i have tried lots of things but not worked. I am started to thinking if android does not support different oriented views.

Comment: See my last xml portion.There is a linear layout which is horizontal oriented.Inside this layout there is a linearLayout whose orientation is vertical.whatever you place inside that layout it will be vertical.which is as you told above.

Comment: i understand what you do, but strangely everything looks horizontal

Comment: I edited again.Now see the last portion of the xml.is it your expected layout?if not please be sure about horizontal and vertical.